# Django: Получить кастомный объект если не найдено ничего

Tags: django

Мне нужно построить статистику сессий пользователя. Проблема возникает что присутствуют моменты когда в периоде времени нет данных. и их надо отобразить дефолтными значениями.
получаю ответ:

```
[
    {
        "time": "2021-06-14T11:57:00",
        "ip": "255.253.250.255",
        "count": 3
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-06-14T12:02:00",
        "ip": "255.253.250.255",
        "count": 3
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-06-14T12:12:00",
        "ip": "255.253.250.255",
        "count": 3
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-06-14T12:17:00",
        "ip": "255.253.250.255",
        "count": 3
    }
]
```

а нужно:

```
[
    {
        "time": "2021-06-14T11:57:00",
        "ip": "255.253.250.255",
        "count": 3
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-06-14T12:02:00",
        "ip": "255.253.250.255",
        "count": 3
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-06-14T12:07:00",
        "ip": 0,
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-06-14T12:12:00",
        "ip": "255.253.250.255",
        "count": 3
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-06-14T12:17:00",
        "ip": "255.253.250.255",
        "count": 3
    }
]
```

имеется такой код:

```
class SessionModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'statistic'

    time = models.DateTimeField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    source = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    token = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    count = models.IntegerField(blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.time = timezone.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0).isoformat(' ')
        return super(SessionModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class TokenStatView(APIView):
    serializer_class = SessionSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        base = datetime.datetime.today()
        date_list = [(base - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5) * x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') for x in range(24 * 12)]

        token_or_ip = kwargs.get('pk')
        if token_or_ip.count('.') == 3 and all(0 <= int(num) < 256 for num in token_or_ip.rstrip().split('.')):
            result = SessionModel.objects.filter(ip=token_or_ip, time__in=date_list).values('time',
                                                                                                     'ip').annotate(
                count=Sum('count')).order_by('ip', 'time')
        else:
            result = SessionModel.objects.filter(token=token_or_ip, time__in=date_list).values('time',
                                                                                                        'ip').annotate(
                count=Sum('count')).order_by('ip', 'time')

        return Response(result, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

Переопределите `get_queryset`. преобразуйте его в список и вставьте нужные значения в нужные места. можете сформировать новый  список  (так проще будет).

Судя по примеру, интервал должен быть в 5 минут. можете сами отсчитывать время, либо от прошлого добавленного в список, объекта

Также, можете написать фильтр, если используете `django-filters`, чтобы не засорять view.